# Overriding default behaviour for img and a with AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently trying to write a custom directive for `<a>` and `<img>`. I have some test code where I want to see to get the src of an image. However, the code below does not seem to fire when I navigate to a page with an img tag.

Any ideas why?

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  angular.directive('img', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        src: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.src);
      }
    };
  }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull the source with this code.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('img', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs.src);
        }
    };
}]);
```